# Update Trigger - Updating table other than trigger table

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, triggers

userNotesTable:

```
_id integer primary key,
name text,
extra text
```

userRemindersTable:

```
_id integer primary key,
noteid ineteger,
FOREIGN KEY(noteid) REFERENCES userNotesTable(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

INSERT TRIGGER:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name
AFTER INSERT ON userRemindersTable BEGIN INSERT INTO searchTable (id,noteId)
VALUES (new.id,new.noteId); 
END;
```

UPDATE TRIGGER:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name
AFTER UPDATE ON userRemindersTable BEGIN 
UPDATE searchTable SET _id = new._id, noteid = new.noteid WHERE id IS new.id;
UPDATE searchTable SET name = new.name, extra  = new.extra WHERE id IS new.noteid;
END;
```

This is the current code for the databases and its specific triggers for the reminders table. What I am having difficulty doing is to **select** the specific **name** and **extra** from the user notes table from the specific `noteid` in the reminders table all within the update trigger.

The `id` and `noteid` are inserted into the reminders and search table when an insert happens, but I want to be able to update the search table with the specific name and extra from the user notes table, is this possible?

Comment: Was it intentional that both the INSERT and UPDATE triggers share the same name (`trigger_name`)?

Comment: Yup. Any suggestions on how I can select name and extra from user notes table with a specific noteid from reminders?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few anomalies in the presented code, so I've worked with it, modified it a little so that it runs, and given enough of an example that you should be able to work with it to get it to do what you want.

The main problem here is that to update a table other than the one triggering the ON UPDATE trigger, it's necessary to join tables, and SQLite [doesn't support such an update statement](http://sqlite.org/lang_update.html).

I used a nice little utility called SQLite Studio to re-create the scenario. It's available here: http://sqlitestudio.pl/?act=download

Here's the code I used to re-create your database:

---

```
CREATE TABLE userNotesTable ( 
    _id   INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    name  TEXT,
    extra TEXT 
);

CREATE TABLE userRemindersTable ( 
    _id    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    noteid INTEGER,
    FOREIGN KEY ( noteid ) REFERENCES userNotesTable ( _id ) ON DELETE CASCADE 
);

CREATE TABLE searchTable ( 
    _id    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    noteId INTEGER,
    name   TEXT,
    extra  TEXT 
);
```

---

I noticed that some of the ID columns were named `_id`, and others `id`, so I named them all `_id`. When the triggers were created, the code within didn't catch that; instead I got a run-time error when the trigger executed.

In the triggers, note that I've added FOR EACH ROW to each of them. This allows each row that's INSERTed or UPDATEd to be processed, rather than just doing one blanket update statement per execution. I also omitted the update of the ID column in `searchTable`, as the update set the column value to be itself.

Here is the trigger creation DDL:

---

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_userRemindersTable_onInsert
AFTER INSERT ON userRemindersTable 
for each row
begin
    INSERT INTO searchTable (_id, noteId)
    VALUES (new._id, new.noteId); 
end;


CREATE TRIGGER trg_userRemindersTable_onUpdate
AFTER UPDATE ON userRemindersTable 
for each row
begin


    UPDATE searchTable
    SET name = (SELECT name
      FROM userNotesTable
      WHERE _id = new.noteId)
    where noteId = new.noteId;             


    UPDATE searchTable
    SET extra = (SELECT extra
      FROM userNotesTable
      WHERE _id = new.noteId)
    where noteId = new.noteId;              


END;
```

---

I tested creating records in the `userNotesTable`. Then, when I created some records in the `userRemindersTable`, the INSERT trigger fired and inserted a corresponding record into the `searchTable`.

When the records in `userRemindersTable` are updated, the `name` and `extra` fields in `searchTable` are set based on the corresponding `noteid`.

I'm assuming that there are some omitted fields in `userRemindersTable`, as there's not really anything to update (to test, I updated the `_id` field). Further, for the INSERT trigger, I deliberately left out the setting of the `name` and `extra` fields, as they were not mentioned in the question, although they probably also need to be added to the INSERT statement in the ON INSERT trigger.